# If $f : A \subset M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function then $dd^c f = 0 \Rightarrow f = cte.$

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am trying to prove the following:

If $f : A \subset M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function such that $dd^c f = 0$ then $f = c,$ where $M$ is a compact Kähler manifold, $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
We remember that $dd^c = 2i\partial\overline{\partial}$ and $\partial$, $\overline{\partial}$ are de Dolbeault operators.

Comment: What's $M$ in $C^\infty(M)$?

Comment: Does "cte" stand for "constant"? If so, then this implication is false, even in the case of one variable. The equation $dd^cf=0$ is satisfied by any function that is the sum of a holomorphic function plus an anti-holomorphic function.

Comment: @JackLee, I am sorry for the mistakes. What about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Every solution to $dd^c f=0$ is harmonic.
2. Every harmonic function on a compact manifold is constant.

Comment: For the first assumption, we may use some Kahler identities and the second is immediate, from the short I know, via Hodge theorem.